# LLVM not compiling

Tags: ocaml, llvm

I keep getting this error when making for my ocaml llvm program

> llvm[0]: Reconfiguring with
>   /home/me/.opam/4.01.0/build/llvm.3.5/configure

it stays like that and doesn't stop.

Comment: what package are you trying to install? What commands are you invoking

Comment: also, what is your operating system, and do you use opam, and, id yes, what version of opam are you using?

Comment: @ivg I'm using mint, and opam is 4.01.0
I've already installed the packages. 
Before it hangs, I get this:

/home/me/.opam/4.01.0/build/llvm.3.5/bindings/ocaml/Makefile.ocaml:438: warning: overriding commands for target `/Release+Asserts/examples/OCaml-Kaleidoscope-Ch2'
/home/me/.opam/4.01.0/build/llvm.3.5/Makefile.rules:1432: warning: ignoring old commands for target `/Release+Asserts/examples/OCaml-Kaleidoscope-Ch2'

Comment: well, llvm 3.5 is about 16 MB maybe it just tries to download it. But anyway, I suggest you to use newer version of opam. I'm not sure, that ppa works in mint, but if it is, the following will do it:
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:avsm/ppa;
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get --yes install opam

Comment: @ivg It said that the package could not be open or parsed.